# Toolbar Menu not clickable on Android API 19

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying have my android app work on multiple versions and have ran into a jam with API 19.  I have a toolbar that is not clickable.  The toolbar shows but clicking is not firing.  The app works fine for API 21 and 23.  I also notice that the view pager is also not clickable but the swipe works.  Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbarGeneral"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Style:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
 </style>
 <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity:

```
 public class MasterActivity : AppCompatActivity, View.IOnClickListener//, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
{

    //private XmppClient _xmppClient;
    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    //private bool _shouldImportContact;
    //private bool _shouldInitialiseSystem;
    private AppCompatActivity _context;
    private MasterPageChangeListener _pageChangeListener;
    private IMenuItem _editMenu;
    private SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;
    private int _fragmentPos;
    private Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] _masterFragments;
    private CRUDRepository<FacebookInfo> _facebookCRUD;
    private FacebookInfo _facebookInfo;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        _facebookInfo = new FacebookInfo();
        _facebookCRUD = new CRUDRepository<FacebookInfo>();
        _fragmentPos = Intent.GetIntExtra("FragmentPos", 0);
        _dbConnection = SQLiteHelper.GetConnection();
        try
        {
            _context = this;

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Master); //Set view the Master view

            Toolbar.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            this.SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            _mViewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
            _mViewPager.Adapter = new MasterAdapter(base.SupportFragmentManager, _masterFragments, titleLabels);

            _mViewPager.SetCurrentItem(_fragmentPos, true);

            TabLayout tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(_mViewPager);

            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.SetOnClickListener(this);

            //Create the pageChangeListener class so that the page selected is known
            _pageChangeListener = new MasterPageChangeListener(this, _mViewPager);
            _mViewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(_pageChangeListener);


        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            var data = Ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

OnPrepareOptionsMenu and OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
 public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {

        if (_pageChangeListener.tabPosition == 0)
            _editMenu.SetVisible(true);
        else if (_pageChangeListener.tabPosition == 1 || _pageChangeListener.tabPosition == 2)
            _editMenu.SetVisible(false);
        return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);          
    }


    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        var inflater = MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu, menu);
        _editMenu = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_add);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please narrow your code down. Don't dump _everything_ here, just relevant parts....

Comment: Narrow it how?  I have broken up the code in bits: Toolbar.xml, style.xml, mainactivity with only the Oncreate, along with the 2 menu functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue directly relates to this:

1) You need to define `app:` correctly to `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"`

2) You need to change the word `app:layout_behaviour` to `app:layout_behavior`

Feel free to edit your original question with the respective code so this answer makes more sense! (As more source code was revealed in a PM)